# 'Root Disk does Not exist' - How do I get it back?

Tags: 10.04, wubi, root

When booting Ubuntu I suddenly get the information that my root disk does not exist. I am running Wubi and Ubuntu Version 10.04. I  tried the following:

Rebooting Windows, then rebooting Ubuntu.

Entering Ubuntu via USB-Version (to save some of my data).

Searching for lost file via Recuva in Windows (XP).

CHKDSK via Windows.

None of it worked. Root Disk is still missing. 
I definitely need some of the Data which is saved on Ubuntu. I don't have a back up file (will def do that in the Future). 
Is reinstallation the only Way out? Or what else can I do? I really Need my data!

Help is always appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Saskia

Comment: search whether `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk.` is available .

Answer (score 0):

From WubiGuide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu

Never try to correct Wubi boot problems by reinstalling Grub2. This will prevent Windows from booting and will not fix the Wubi install.

Ubuntu cannot be booted if Windows has not been shut down cleanly, you have to clear the Windows filesystem from Windows (there is no chkdsk equivalent for Linux yet).

If Wubi fails to start,

- boot into Windows
- run chkdsk /r from Windows on the same drive where you installed
  Ubuntu
- shutdown cleanly and then try to boot into Ubuntu again.

Note that sometimes files are moved by Windows into a hidden folder called C:\found.000.

You need to have C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk. If you do not see this file, look for found.000. You need to change the Windows Explorer settings to be able to see hidden folders first, then move the files from found.000 to their original location. Sometimes the entire \ubuntu\disks directory may be recovered to \found.000 in a folder named dir0000.chk.

The data from Wubi installation cannot be recovered by booting Ubuntu from USB. This is because Wubi does not create separate partitions for Ubuntu, but keeps everything in a big file **C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk** inside the Windows partition. If this file is damaged, or deleted, recovery depends on repairing or undeleting the damaged file using Windows tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Did a check again but it didn't help. Couldn't find any hidden folders either. :(

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately, if the C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk is gone, there is no way to get the data in Ubuntu back. Sorry.

Comment: I read something about Wubi 'The main disk used for the Wubi install does not exist. Uninstall Wubi, then reinstall wubi.exe and pack it in One Folder with ubuntu desktop Iso.' What do you think?

Comment: Does uninstalling Wubi mean that I'm gonna loose my Data?

Comment: Could you copy the link of where the uninstall-reinstall advice is? I am not sure if uninstalling and reinstalling will help. The main thing would be to find the root.disk file. If that file is gone for ever, the data is gone too.

Comment: Here it is: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1880031

Comment: Doesn't look like the same problem. The original poster at the ubuntuforums' thread had a new wubi install that didn't boot. There was no data to recover. The process of reinstalling wubi overwrote the possibly corrupt root.disk and created a new one.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I hope someone else with more experience has some ideas.

Comment: Shall I try to replace wubildr file with a New one?

Comment: Please edit the main question and add this question. I don't know the answer.